# create a fadeout effect on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

im having trouble with creating this.

Im using jQuery as my main JS library. I wanted to use the fade() function to create a div, which when rolled-over would fade to show content underneath.

Say for instance a div with grey background with an image on top, which would fade to reveal content underneath. Is this possible? Im not very good with JS/jQuery

Comment: Please provide code if you want a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dkpgQ/2/ ?

EDIT: code...

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
    </div>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#overlay").mouseover(function() {
   $("#overlay").fadeOut("slow"); 
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
}

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/dkpgQ/3/ and help me on how i can stop the constant fade when mouse is hovering

Comment: @Belinda - Really...There you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery

```
$('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
   // Animation complete.
});
```

This [link](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) contains more explanation.

Or you can use the jquery animate function as explained in this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-animate-fade-out-at-certain-position)

Comment: thanks for the links, it helps me in my quest to actually learn